# Vue-router: esconder componentes na troca de página

Tags: vue.js, front-end, vue-router

Estou aprendendo vuejs e agora me deparei com uma dificuldade na parte de esconder componentes quando mostrar as outras rotas por exemplo:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <ion-icon name="help-circle-outline" class="help"></ion-icon>
     <menuv></menuv><!-- componente a ser escondido quando a rota for carregada -->
     <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Como faço para esconder um componente assim que a rota for carregada?

Comment: Cara isto envolve um contexto bem maior do que este código que colocou aqui. Basicamente você terá que colocar um **v-if** na tag menu validando conforme a rota.

Comment: ~Utilize `vuex`~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um [plugin](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) para armazenar algumas configurações:

*./components/config/index.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const globalConfig = new Vue({
    data: {
        menu: {
            show: true,
            hide_from_pages: [ 'Contact' ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show_or_hide: function(page) {
            this.menu.show = this.menu.hide_from_pages.includes(page) ? false : true;
        }
    }
});
globalConfig.install = () => {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, 'globalConfig', {
        get () { return globalConfig }
    });
};

export default globalConfig
```

Importe no arquivo *main.js*

```
...
import globalConfig from './config'
...

Vue.use(globalConfig);
```

Adicione a função [`scrollBehavior`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior) em sua instancia `VueRouter` chamando o método `show_menu`, passe como parâmetro o nome da pagina carregada.

```
new Router({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
        { path: '/about', name: 'About', component: About },
        { path: '/contact', name: 'Contact', component: Contact },
    ],
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        globalConfig.show_menu(to.name)
    }
})
```

Utilize a diretiva [`v-show`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) em no componente:

```
<menuv v-show="globalConfig.menu.show"></menuv>
```

#### Referências

- [Plugins](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)
- [Scroll Behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#scroll-behavior)
- [Renderização Condicional](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)